# Using Sequence Primary key to generate value for other column

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, annotations, hibernate-annotations

I am looking for solution to use Sequence key for constructing the value for other column.

Say for example, i have one sequence primary key field of "Id" and other field name "ex_Id" in my entity class.

The primary key id will be generated during the persistence automatically, but i want to know how to set my "ex_Id". As that need to have same primary key also part of it.

Example:

Id - **123456**
ex_Id - **EX_ID_123456**

Do we have any annotation to achieve this? so i can do as part of entity itself before persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick hack that I've come up with:

You have to create a separate Entity to save your `Ex_Id` that will do the required work for you:

```
@Entity
public class ExId {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String ex_Id;

    public setExId(long primaryKey) {
        this.ex_Id = Integer.toString(this.id) +  "_" + Long.toString(primaryKey);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.ex_Id;
    }
}
```

This is your main entity that is using the above class:

```
@Entity 
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ExId ex_id;

    ...

    public setExId() {
        this.ex_Id.setExId(this.id);
    }

}
```

Now, as you know that  generated value for `@Id` will be created when the entity will be saved, so you need to save this entity first, and then using the `@Id` that's returned, you can do the required work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    session.save(myEntity);
    myEntity.setExId();
    session.update(myEntity.getExId());
    ...
}
```

*P.S.: I didn't compiled this code so this may be error prone.*